# Lançamento de Exceção

Tags: javascript, exceção

Estou estudando JS, montei o seguinte código e estou com dúvidas sobre o comportamento dessa exceção no JS.

```
const getSales2 = async () => {
    await knex("tbl_vendas")
        .select(knex.raw("tbl_vendas.id_vendas, tbl_vendedores.nome AS vendedor, " +
            "tbl_clientes.nome_razaosocial AS cliente, tbl_vendas.data, tbl_vendas.hora, " +
            "tbl_vendas.cupom, tbl_vendas.total, tbl_vendas.p1, tbl_vendas.p2, tbl_vendas.p3, " +
            "tbl_vendas.p4, tbl_vendas.p5, tbl_vendas.p6, tbl_vendas.p7, tbl_vendas.p8, troco"))            
        .where("tbl_vendas.upload", 0)           
        .then(sales => {
            const rows = sales.map(sale => {
                return knex("tbl_vendas_itens")
                    .select("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas_itens AS id_item", "tbl_produtos.descricao",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.qtde", "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_unitario", "tbl_vendas_itens.desconto",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_total")
                    .leftOuterJoin("tbl_produtos", "tbl_vendas_itens.id_produtos", "tbl_produtos.id_produtos")
                    .where("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas", "=", sale.id_vendas)
                    .then(sales_items => {
                        return sales_items.map(item => {
                            const newItem = { ...item };
                            return newItem;
                        })
                    })
                    .then(sales_items => {
                        throw('Itens - Testando exceção');
                        const newRow = { ...sale, itens: [...sales_items] };
                        return newRow;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        throw(error);
                    });
            });
            return Promise.all(rows);
        })
        .then(async (values) => {
            await bulkWriteInMongo();
            await setUploadInMysql();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`V2 - Exceção Principal - ${error}`);
        })
}
```

Como podem ver eu estou forçando uma exceção nos itens das vendas (throw('Itens - Testando exceção')).

Então eu esperava que no retorno do Promise.all a exceção interna fosse lançada e capturada pelo Catch da Exceção Principal, até acontece, mas apenas uma vez.

Eu recebo as seguintes mensagens:

```
Itens - Testando exceção
V2 - Exceção Principal - Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
...
```

O resultado que eu esperava eram essas 2 primeiras linhas, com a exceção dos itens e a exceção principal, mas nas linhas seguintes só é exibido a mensagem de exceção dos itens.
Eu estava esperando que após cada exceção dos itens fosse lançada também a exceção principal, dessa maneira:

```
Itens - Testando exceção
V2 - Exceção Principal - Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
V2 - Exceção Principal - Itens - Testando exceção
Itens - Testando exceção
V2 - Exceção Principal - Itens - Testando exceção
...
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender porque isso não acontece nesse código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Promise.all` recebe um array de *promises* e o transforma numa única *promise*, que irá resolver num array de resultados, ou então rejeitar um erro.

Essa rejeição funciona como a rejeição de qualquer outra promise, é apenas uma rejeição, não uma rejeição para cada promise que deu errado, então ele só irá cair no `catch` uma vez.

O que você poderia utilizar nesse caso é o `Promise.allSettled`. Diferente do `all`, o `allSettled` nunca rejeita erros, ele te devolve um array de resultados, que podem ter o status `fulfilled` ou `rejected`, e então você só precisa iterar sobre esses resultados e tratar os erros:

```
const getSales2 = async () => {
    await knex("tbl_vendas")
        .select(knex.raw("tbl_vendas.id_vendas, tbl_vendedores.nome AS vendedor, " +
            "tbl_clientes.nome_razaosocial AS cliente, tbl_vendas.data, tbl_vendas.hora, " +
            "tbl_vendas.cupom, tbl_vendas.total, tbl_vendas.p1, tbl_vendas.p2, tbl_vendas.p3, " +
            "tbl_vendas.p4, tbl_vendas.p5, tbl_vendas.p6, tbl_vendas.p7, tbl_vendas.p8, troco"))            
        .where("tbl_vendas.upload", 0)           
        .then(sales => {
            const rows = sales.map(sale => {
                return knex("tbl_vendas_itens")
                    .select("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas_itens AS id_item", "tbl_produtos.descricao",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.qtde", "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_unitario", "tbl_vendas_itens.desconto",
                        "tbl_vendas_itens.vl_total")
                    .leftOuterJoin("tbl_produtos", "tbl_vendas_itens.id_produtos", "tbl_produtos.id_produtos")
                    .where("tbl_vendas_itens.id_vendas", "=", sale.id_vendas)
                    .then(sales_items => {
                        return sales_items.map(item => {
                            const newItem = { ...item };
                            return newItem;
                        })
                    })
                    .then(sales_items => {
                        throw('Itens - Testando exceção');
                        const newRow = { ...sale, itens: [...sales_items] };
                        return newRow;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        throw(error);
                    });
            });
            return Promise.allSettled(rows);
        })
        .then(results => {
            results.forEach(async result => {
                if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
                    await bulkWriteInMongo(mongo, "vendas", result.value, 'V2');
                    await setUploadInMysql('tbl_vendas', 'id_vendas', indexes);
                } else {
                    console.log(`V2 - Exceção Principal - ${result.reason}`);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Obs: Eu acredito que este código tenha erros, especialmente na parte do `setUploadInMysql` que está fazendo update em todas as `indexes`.

Utilize-o apenas como referência para como tratar o `allSettled`.

Comment: Sobre a sua observação do indexes, é que eu ocultei a parte do código onde eu declaro e alimento essa constante, pois não era o foco da minha dúvida. Na verdade eu não preciso desse catch interno, dessa forma se der erro simplesmente cai no Catch Principal, mas fiquei curioso sobre esse comportamento e postei a dúvida.

Comment: Pelo que entendi da sua explicação o Promise.all deveria tentar resolver a primeira promise, a mesma seria rejeitada e entraria no seu catch, seu catch por sua vez lançaria uma exceção, essa exceção iria para o Promise.all que rejeita a promise inteira e não tentaria resolver mais nada. Não entendo porque ele exibe o log das outras promises!!!

Comment: Bruno, as promises em JavaScript tem o comportamento _eager_ e não _lazy_, no memento que elas são criadas, elas já começam a ser processadas. O `Promise.all` apenas espera pela resolução delas, mas mesmo antes de você passa-las para o `Promise.all` elas já estão sendo processadas. Por isso que todas as mensagens são imprimidas, todas elas são processadas ao mesmo tempo, independente de uma dar erro ou não.

Comment: Nossa... que conceito brabo de entender, mas ainda vou conseguir... kkkkkkkkk Obrigado amigo... Não conheço esses termos eager e lazy, onde posso ler sobre eles?